# Save/[Save As] dialogue box on download using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a functionality and I need to offer user a PDF to download. I am able to do in successfully to some extend, like user will get a email with download link like

```
http://www.abc.com/balbla.pdf
```

But this is opening up the PDF in the browser window, I am thinking of offering a way so that when user click on the link he/she should be prompt to save it using standard save/save as box

How can this be done in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control this with the headers, have a look at this answer for a wordpress style of doing it: [How can I force a file download in the WordPress backend?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/how-can-i-force-a-file-download-in-the-wordpress-backend)

Otherwise you use your webserver to force-download pdf:s, but the above example might be what you were searching for.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is so easy and everyone can do it.

1. zip the file to give download
2. link the zip file to url.
   (e.g.`<a href="../../../No_5.zip">No-5 downloadable</a>`)
3. View the result. After clicking "No-5 downloadable" link, open and save as dialog box will appear. I hope this way helps.